# JavaScript append gone crazy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a simple 3 grid gallery, the images inside it are all with different heights and I was after a tiled gallery... So I have made one that works with a bit of JavaScript.

However, when I tried to add another gallery in the same page, something weird happened, live preview here: http://loai.directory/test/gallery

The HTML, CSS and JS can be found fully placed in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aY5Gu

As you can see in the live preview, all the gridElemetns in grid3 are appending to grid3 in all the threeGrid galleries! After trying to debug, I have concluded that the problem is from the JS:

```
//Three Grids System
   var gridElement = $(".gridElement", ".grid3");
   GalleryGrid(); $(window).resize(GalleryGrid);
   function GalleryGrid() {
      var grid3 = $('.threeGrids .grid3');
      var width = $(window).width();
      if (width < 1024 && width > 770) {
         var grid1 = $('.threeGrids .grid1');
         var grid2 = $('.threeGrids .grid2');

         for (var i = 0; i < gridElement.length; i++) {
            if (i < gridElement.length / 2) {
               grid1.append(gridElement[i]);
            } else {
               grid2.append(gridElement[i]);
            }
         }
      } else {
         grid3.append(gridElement);
      }
   }
```

What is going wrong? I can't seem to be able to go figure out what is wrong from there.

Comment: Your question is really confusing. What is it that you expected to happen? You're selecting by class, so "gridElement" will always involve *all* the elements inside *all* the ".grid3" containers.

Comment: Yes, that is what suppose to happen, but what is happening now is all the gridElemtns inside all the grid3 will append to each grid3 in each gallery... so for example as you can see, grid3 in the second gallery is also appearing in grid one, and so on..

Comment: Yes, well that's what your code is telling it to do. If you want to select individual particular elements, you should use id attributes and unique id values.

Comment: Are you trying to create a fluid grid width dependent?

Comment: yes, I already created one, live example: http://loaidesign.co.uk/portfolio try and resize the screen, it is using the same code. But I just discovered that if I added another gallery under it, this problem will apepar

Comment: why don't you use only css to get this behavior, [take a look here](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids)?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.threeGrids` and `.grid1`... appear more than one time on your page. Therefore jquery automatically appends things to all of them.

Try selecting by something like:

```
$('.wrapper').each(
  function(){
    var grids = $(this).find('.threeGrids');
    (...do manipulation with grids...)
  }
);
```

This way you enter each `.wrapper` separately and deal with only elements that are inside it.

Comment: Just tried it, and it didn't work - it added all the elements from all grid1,2 and 3 to grid 3 in the first gallery